# how can i get json property which has multiple spaces within the name?

Tags: javascript, json

```
"technicalData": [
      {
        "Technologie": "Bluetooth Low Energy 4.0",
        "Größe (L x B x H)": "34.4 x 32.5 x 13 mm",
        "Gewicht": "018 kg",
        "Software": "Für die Arbeit benötigt, aber nicht im Lieferumfang enthalten. Registrierung für kostenlose Software-Verwendung und Premium-Services unter: www.bosch-trackmytools.com",
        "Batterie": "CR 2032",
        "Batterie Lebensdauer": "3 J",
        "IP Schutzklasse": "IP 67",
        "Robustheit": "IK 04",
        "Befestigung": "2-Komponenten-Klebstoff oder Kabelhalter GCA 30-9 Professional"
      }
    ]
```

I need to get "Größe (L x B x H)" butcant because it has multiple spaces, ["naming it "] doesnt work

Comment: Can you show us what you tried when you said you tried by "["naming it"]"? It works fine for me when I do it that way

Comment: for (const d of dt.technicalData) {
                html += `
                        <div class="col-lg-3">Größe (L x B x H)</div>
                        <div class="col-lg-9">${d.GrößeLxBxH}</div>`
            }
I needed to print data on ther awkward name and I couldnt do it , maybe i was doing it wrong, rarely i see json property name with white space 

i was trying this ${d.["GrößeLxBxH"]} but i guess that was terribly wrong so i removed white space and did it the easier way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you have to proper define your json dictionary as follow:

```
json_dict = {"technicalData": [
      {
        "Technologie": "Bluetooth Low Energy 4.0",
        "Größe (L x B x H)": "34.4 x 32.5 x 13 mm",
        "Gewicht": "018 kg",
        "Software": "Für die Arbeit benötigt, aber nicht im Lieferumfang enthalten. Registrierung für kostenlose Software-Verwendung und Premium-Services unter: www.bosch-trackmytools.com",
        "Batterie": "CR 2032",
        "Batterie Lebensdauer": "3 J",
        "IP Schutzklasse": "IP 67",
        "Robustheit": "IK 04",
        "Befestigung": "2-Komponenten-Klebstoff oder Kabelhalter GCA 30-9 Professional"
      }
    ]
}
```

Afterwards, you can get the property with this `print()` statement. Caution, the dictionary of interest is inside an array!

```
print(json_dict['technicalData'][0]['Größe (L x B x H)'])
# 34.4 x 32.5 x 13 mm
```

Comment: i kinda needed to do it while looping through array, nvm i got it done, thank you for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

Hi that shouldn't be a problem at all, don't forget that your json is inside an array, but I'm sure that if you do this, you will be fine.

```
technicalData[0]["Größe (L x B x H)"]
```

It should return "34.4 x 32.5 x 13mm"

Comment: totally forgot about that, I ended up removing all white space. thanks